# Two form on the same view in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem in Codeigniter when i have two upload forms on the same view/site. It seems Codeigniter recognizes only submit from one form. Even if i change the input name in the form, problem still exists. 
Below is my view and controler:

View:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/upload/do_upload_ac');?>
                    <input type="file" name="actives"  />
                    <br /><br />
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add Active Emails" />
                    </form>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/upload/do_upload_un');?>
                    <input type="file" name="unactives"  />
                    <br /><br />
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add Active Emails" />
                    </form>
```

And the controler:

```
public function do_upload_ac()
    {

            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'csv';
            $config['max_size']             = 0;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('actives'))
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Csv Data Import failed!! Please check the file size or file type!');
                    //$this->load->view('admin/muc', $error);
                    redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/admin/muc');
            }
            else
            {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    $filename_ac = $this->upload->data('full_path');

                    $this->Upload_model->insert_csv_ac($filename_ac);
                    $this->Upload_model->clean_temp_ac();
                    $this->Upload_model->truncate_temp_ac();             

                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Csv Data Imported Succesfully!');
                    //$this->load->view('success', $data);
                    //unlink($filename_ac); 
                    redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/admin/muc');
            }


    }

    public function do_upload_un()
    {
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');                
            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'csv';
            $config['max_size']             = 0;    



            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('unactives'))
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Csv Data Import failed!! Please check the file size or file type!');
                    //$this->load->view('admin/muc', $error);
                    redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/admin/muc');
            }
            else
            {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    $filename_ac = $this->upload->data('full_path');

                    $this->Upload_model->insert_csv_un($filename_un);
                    $this->Upload_model->clean_temp_un();
                    $this->Upload_model->truncate_temp_un();             

                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Csv Data Imported Succesfully!');
                    //$this->load->view('success', $data);
                    unlink($filename_un); 
                    redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/admin/muc');
            }


    }
```

I was searching here for similar problem, but i just found uploading multiple files at once. Any ideas? And thank you all.

Comment: give your forms an ID like id="form1" and id="form2" then use Jquery function to submit the form

Comment: Thank you, but its not working. Any solution without jquery?

Comment: can you please end the form with ```<?php echo form_close(); ?>``` instead ```</form>```. And use ```<input type="submit">``` instead button.

Comment: I did.But my problem is still here.....Is it actually possible to have two upload forms on the same view, and two similar functions to upload in controler?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, to give you an understanding of multiple submit, I have rendered a sample view for you. I have created following view

[image]

With this code

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3" style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px grey">
        <form action="<?php echo base_url().'admin/upload/do_upload_ac'?>" method="post" id="form1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label > Upload 1</label>
                <input type="file" name="file1" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="submitOne()">Upload Image1</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px grey">
        <form action="<?php echo base_url().'admin/upload/do_upload_un'?>" method="post" id="form2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label > Upload 2</label>
                <input type="file" name="file1" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="submitTwo()">Upload Image2</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this Script

```
<script>
function submitOne()
{

    $('#form1').submit();
}
function submitTwo()
{

    $('#form2').submit();
}
</script>
```

I press first button I get

[image]

Similarly If i press second button it shows me form2 will be submitted. What you do once the form is submitted is all in the URL where you are submitting the form.

Comment: Thank you sir,but sorry, still not working. I get the jquery alerts, and it seems everything is fine, but upload only happens with the first form.

Comment: try now, i have removed alerts and placed url in form action

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working with no update required. But you should change html form close with codeigniter's `form_close()` or user html form tag to start form.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: i mean to say that codeigniter doesn't have any rule that you can use one form in one view. form individually works & post it's fields and input values to the action given in it.means $_FILES['actives'] will posted in action/method 'do_upload_ac' and $_FILES['unactives'] will posted in action/method 'do_upload_un'